# flash as3 How to remove part of byteArray?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, arrays

var fData:ByteArray = new ByteArray();

I need to remove some bytes in this array, but can't find any public method in Flash to do that.
I searched something like fData.remove(start,length) but with no success.

here is a code

```
    function _dlProgressHandler(evt:ProgressEvent):void { //this is progressEvent for URLStream

............... ///some code

var ff:ByteArray = new ByteArray();

stream.readBytes(ff,0,stream.bytesAvailable);
fileData.writeBytes(ff,0,ff.length); //stream writes into fileData byteArray

//and here is cutter:

fileData.position=0;
fileData.writeBytes(ff,100,fileData.length);
fileData.length=fileData.length-100);

}
```

So, fileData cut itself unpredictably sometimes.
Sometimes old blocks're found twice, sometimes they're not found at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always just only read the bytes that you want, which will have the same effect as discarding the bytes that you don't want. As a very simple example, assume you have a ByteArray that is 10 bytes long and you want to discard the first 3 bytes:

```
var newBytes:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
newBytes.writeBytes(fData, 2, 7);
```

So instead of removing the bytes that you don't want from fData, you just create a new ByteArray and only get they bytes that you want from fData.

Obviously, if the sequence of bytes you want to remove is not just a sequence from the beginning or end of fData it will be a little more complicated, but the method remains the same: read the bytes that you want, instead of removing the ones you don't.

Comment: I wonder if there's a way to set the points he wants to remove to null and shift the remainder of the array, I would imagine you would still have to shift every single element (depending on how this is actually implemented under the hood) but might be worth the CPU cost to save the memory depending on how big the ByteArray is, if running out of RAM is an issue just reading to a new one doesn't seem like a great solution (albeit possibly the only one).

Comment: can I write to itself?
like fData.writeBytes(fData, 2, 7);  ?
I think, no =)

Comment: @shaunhusain good point, not sure what the solution would be if the ByteArray is very large.

Comment: @EL2002 does an intermediate array not work for your scenario? Why do you have to write directly to the initial byte array?

Comment: @Pixel Elephant > to optimize, because byteArray is very large.

Answer (score 3):

AS-3 is actually very nice sometimes. This removes bytes from your array anywhere you want. Beginning, middle or the end. Just need to check indices to avoid `IndexOutOfBounds`

```
var array: ByteArray = ...; // create the byte array or load one
var index: int = 4;
var count: int = 5;

array.position = index;
array.writeBytes(array, index + count, array.length - (index + count));
array.length = array.length - count;
```

- I tested this and it works well, just the checks are missing
- a byte array **can** write to itself